# Gnuplot, conditional vectorstyle gives an error

Tags: conditional-statements, gnuplot

I have a comma-separated text file like this:

```
1386708463,830
1386708473,830
1386708484,830
1386708497,-830
1386708508,-830
1386708518,-840
1386708528,-840
1386708538,-840
1386708686,-950
1386708696,-960
1386708706,-960
1386708716,-940
1386708726,-940
```

When the value in column 2 is negative the color must be red otherwise green.

I tried with:

```
plot "< tail -10 meterstanden.txt" using (-100):1:2:0 title "", \
     "< tail -11 meterstanden.txt" using (0):1:($2>0 ? $2:0/0):(0) title "Watt/uur " with vectors arrowstyle 2, \
     "< tail -11 meterstanden.txt" using (0):1:($2<=0 ? $2:0/0):(0) title "Watt/uur " with vectors arrowstyle 1, \
     "< tail -11 meterstanden.txt" using 2:1:2 with labels font "arial, 8"  offset 1.5,0.4
```

But I get this error:

```
plot "< tail -10 meterstanden.txt" using (-100):1:2:0 title "",      "< tail -11 meterstanden.txt" using (0):1:($2>0 ? $2:0/0):(0) title "Watt/uur " with vectors arrowstyle 2,    "< tail -11 meterstanden.txt" using (0):1:($2<=0 ? $2:0/0):(0) title "Watt/uur " with vectors arrowstyle 1,      "< tail -11 meterstanden.txt" using 2:1:2 with labels font "arial, 8"  offset 1.5,0.4


                                                                                                  ^
"figure02_temp.plt", line 37: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

I can not figure out what the problem is, what am I doing wrong?

The complete script is:

```
set output "gnu.png"
set datafile separator ","
set style arrow 1 lw 3 lc rgb "#ff0000"
set style arrow 2 lw 3 lc rgb "#008000"
set style arrow 1 head size screen 0.02,90 # 0.02 is de breedte van het streepje, 90 is een platte streep.
set style arrow 2 head size screen 0.02,90 # 0.02 is de breedte van het streepje, 90 is een platte streep.
set linetype 1  lw 1 pointtype 0 lc rgb"#ff0000"

set bmargin 4 # witruimte onder grafiek
set label font "arial, 8" # grootte font tbv labels in het grafiek

set terminal png notransparent truecolor enhanced
set term png size 500, 450 background rgb "#ffffff"
set ydata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format y "%H:%M:%S"  # dit is de opmaak zoals je hem gaat zien

 #set key outside bot center
 #set key maxrows 1 # aantal regels onder het grafiek (met Watt/uur erin)

set title "Energiestroom" font "arial bold, 14"

set xtics font "arial, 10"
set ytics font "arial, 10"

set ylabel "T i j d - a s" offset 3,1 font "helvetica bold, 14"
set xlabel "W a t t / u u r" offset 0,0.5 font "arial bold, 14"

set grid xtics lc rgb "#dddddd" linewidth 2 lt 1
set grid ytics

set boxwidth 10
set style fill transparent solid 1
unset key

plot "< tail -10 meterstanden.csv" u (-100):1:2:0 title "", \
     "< tail -8 meterstanden.csv" u (0):1:($2<0 ?$2:0/0):(0) notitle with vectors arrowstyle 1, \
     "< tail -8 meterstanden.csv" u (0):1:($2>0 ?$2:0/0):(0) notitle with vectors arrowstyle 1, \
     "< tail -8 meterstanden.csv" u 2:1:2 with labels font "arial, 8"  offset 1.5,0.4
```

The plot is;
http://ccvd.eu/downloads/gnu.png

And after the plot I get the error.

I am VERY glad with your solution. Linux gives me a mail when Gnuplot gives
the trouble. And now thats over, Thanks very much.

And here are the results, a horizontal "histogram" . . . with red and green.
http://ccvd.eu/downloads/gnu1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a warning, not an error. The reason is, that the last 8 lines of the file (assuming, the data you show is the file `meterstanden.csv`) all have negative value. Therefore, the third line in your plot, which is supposed to plot the positive arrows, has only `0/0` values. But the plot is correct.

In your case you can use the `arrowstyle variable` option, which selects the arrow style based on the last column in the `using` statement. That is easier and you don't get any warnings:

```
plot "< tail -10 meterstanden.csv" u (-100):1:2:0 title "", \
     "< tail -8 meterstanden.csv" u (0):1:2:(0):($2 < 0 ? 1 : 2) notitle with vectors arrowstyle variable,\
     "< tail -8 meterstanden.csv" u 2:1:2 with labels font "arial, 8"  offset 1.5,0.4
```